# Migrating Lucene to Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net, solrnet

I have Lucene in my WebSite. How can I migrate Lucene to Solr or ElasticSearch? 
Is Possible importing Lucene indexes to Solr or ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot migrate Lucene to Solr because Solr is built on Lucene. Lucene is the search engine library, Solr is the search server. ES is also a search and analytics Engine.

So you are best off using Solr on top of Lucene, so to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lucene indexes for the searching using the Solr.

As per [this](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-vs-solr.html) guide.

> Can Solr indexes be read by Lucene and vice-versa?
>
> Since Solr uses Lucene under the hood, Solr indexes and Lucene indexes are one and the
> same thing.
> There is technically no such thing as a Solr index, only a Lucene
> index created by a Solr instance.